# Creating a for loop to continue to count

Tags: c++

what would be the code to continue counting with a for loop? like if i wanted put in a char and have it print once on the first line, twice on the second line, third on the third line and so on?

I've tried

```
for (int a; a<5; a++)
cout "L";
```

but this only prints one L per line

i need it to be more like

```
L
LL
LLL
```

Comment: Add up `'L'` characters in a `std::string` variable and print that one at each itereation.

Comment: You need to create another cycle inside that for, to print `L`  `a+1` times.

Comment: what would that look like? thank you guys for the help but im very new and confused

Comment: @codecodecode Don't try to learn the basics here. Your question as is is _off-topic_.

Comment: Why did you use 'for' loop in your code? To repeat same thing multiple times, right? First try to print 5 'L' in 5 lines. (Hint: you would need 1 more for loop.) Then think about how would you limit it to your current line number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need an additional loop if you do not want to use something like `std::string`. The inner loop will add `L` with it's respective amount per line to the output. Once all the amount of `L`s are written, you end the line.

Something like:

```
int main() {

    for (int a = 1; a < 5; a++)
    {
        for (int l = 1; l <= a; l++)
        {
            std::cout << "L";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hey @codecodecode, glad if it helps. In that case you can accept the answer and thus close this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Based to the @Saleem answer, here is a complete sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(auto i=0;i<=5;++i)
    {
        string s(i,'L');
        cout << s.c_str() << endl;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `string` to repeat character desired number of times.

e.g.

```
for(auto i=0;i<=5;++i)
{
    string s(i,'L');
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

This will print:

```
L
LL
LLL
LLLL
LLLLL
```

**Update:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{

    for(auto i=0;i<=5;++i)
    {
        string s(i,'L');
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Make sure you are using modern c++ compiler.